# Python alternative to multiprocessing.Queue() to share data across processes

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I am writing a program that needs to communicate and share audio stream data between multiple processes. This can be done by using `multiprocessing.Queue()`. However, the machine that I'm running this program on returned this error whenever I tried to use `multiprocessing.Queue()`:

> ImportError: This platform lacks a functioning sem_open
>   implementation, therefore, the required synchronization primitives
>   needed will not function, see issue 3770

Is there any other alternative for me to do this?

Comment: Use the `queue` module, it is thread/process safe.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ is it the python 3 version of Queue? I'm using 2.7

Comment: Ah, yes. For python2, the module name is `Queue`. (capital Q).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ seems like it only work for sharing data between Thread but not between Process

Comment: Does the sharing need to happen continuously and in real time, or is it more of a batch thing where you send one sample or file and then another one later?  Is the entire data stream known before you start sending it?

Comment: It needs to happen continuously and in real time. Basically, I'm trying to stream audio recording to Speech-To-Text API